# Use Date to hide columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to be able to create a button that hides all columns that have a date that is more than 30 days out.  Every column has an expected gain date and I'd like to be able to click the button and it shows which gains are projected for 30 days out, another button for 60 days, etc.

I'm sure this is easy for some of you out there but I'm not sure what the formula would be to put in the VBA editor.

Any advice, code or an example would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For an ActiveX button named `CommandButton1`, place the code on the sheet module

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim hdr As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each hdr In CommandButton1.Parent.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
        If IsDate(hdr) Then
            hdr.EntireColumn.Hidden = (hdr < (Now - 30))
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```